# Grub cannot load Windows 10 only BIOS can

Tags: 16.04, grub2, uefi, windows-10, nvme

Dell based Intel i7 6700HQ (Skylake) laptop with HM170 chipset and M.2 PCIe Gen 3.0 x 4 NVMe Samsung Pro 960 SSD formatted with GPT and booting with UEFI.

Cannot boot Windows 10 from grub menu. When option below is chosen the Grub menu goes away, the background says up and the Laptop just freezes.

[image: Grub]

The only solution is to reboot, invoke the BIOS by pressing `F2`, select the Windows EFI and elevate it to a higher boot priority. Screen sample below. After that rebooting automatically takes you into Windows unless you again press F2 at BIOS screen and elevate Ubuntu EFI to higher boot priority.

[image: Boot order]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Dell based Skylake using UEFI and NVMe with AMI BIOS this can be fixed by changing `Firmware TPM` from `enabled` to `disabled` on this screen:

[image: Cropped Firmware TPM]

---

**NOTE:** I thought someone had asked this last month before I got my new laptop. I searched in vane for that question to post this answer there. This problem will affect many people going forward as NVMe and USB-C ThunderBolt3 become more prevalent (they seem to go hand-in-hand) so I decided to post this Q&A so others could benefit. If you can find the original question please close this as a duplicate and I'll post this answer under the original question.